# Unable to set image on Image view after uploading finish

Tags: android

```
public class FragProfile extends SherlockFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_profile, container, false);
        Profile_image = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.frag_imgProfile);
        texusername = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        editbutton = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        textcityname = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        // ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).notifcationbadge
        // .setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).badgeicon.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).EditProfileimage
        // .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).posttext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        editbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent editnameandcity = new Intent(getActivity(),
                        EditnameandCity.class);
                startActivity(editnameandcity);

            }
        });

        SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
                AppConstants.LOGIN_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        member_id = preferences.getString("Member_id", "");
        // member_id = "409";
        image_Url = "http://api.lociiapp.com/TransientStorage/" + member_id
                + ".jpg";
        Profile_image.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                final String[] items = new String[] { "Take from camera",
                        "Select from gallery" };
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,
                        items);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getActivity());

                builder.setTitle("Select Image");
                builder.setAdapter(adapter,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) { // pick
                                                                                    // from
                                                                                    // camera
                                if (item == 0) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                                            MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                                    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(
                                            Environment
                                                    .getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                            "tmp_avatar_"
                                                    + String.valueOf(System
                                                            .currentTimeMillis())
                                                    + ".jpg"));

                                    intent.putExtra(
                                            android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                            mImageCaptureUri);

                                    try {
                                        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                                        startActivityForResult(intent,
                                                PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                } else { // pick from file
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                                    intent.setType("image/*");
                                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                                    startActivityForResult(Intent
                                            .createChooser(intent,
                                                    "Complete action using"),
                                            PICK_FROM_FILE);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
                return false;

            }

        });

        return root;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
            return;

        switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
            doCrop();

            break;

        case PICK_FROM_FILE:
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();

            doCrop();

            break;

        case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

            if (extras != null) {
                Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);

                byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();

                String image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr,
                        Base64.DEFAULT);

                new Uploadimage().execute(image_str);

            }

            File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());

            if (f.exists())
                f.delete();

            break;

        }
    }

    private void doCrop() {
        final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intent.setType("image/*");

        List<ResolveInfo> list = getActivity().getPackageManager()
                .queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

        int size = list.size();

        if (size == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Can not find image crop app",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return;
        } else {
            intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

            intent.putExtra("outputX", 50);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 50);
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            intent.putExtra("scale", true);
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

            if (size == 1) {
                Intent i = new Intent(intent);
                ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

                i.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName,
                        res.activityInfo.name));

                startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
            } else {
                for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                    final CropOption co = new CropOption();

                    co.title = getActivity().getPackageManager()
                            .getApplicationLabel(
                                    res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.icon = getActivity().getPackageManager()
                            .getApplicationIcon(
                                    res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.appIntent = new Intent(intent);

                    co.appIntent
                            .setComponent(new ComponentName(
                                    res.activityInfo.packageName,
                                    res.activityInfo.name));

                    cropOptions.add(co);
                }

                CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(
                        getActivity(), cropOptions);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");
                builder.setAdapter(adapter,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                                startActivityForResult(
                                        cropOptions.get(item).appIntent,
                                        CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                            }
                        });

                builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                        if (mImageCaptureUri != null) {
                            getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(
                                    mImageCaptureUri, null, null);
                            mImageCaptureUri = null;
                        }
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                alert.show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        new username().execute();
//      MtDrawableManager.getInstance().fetchBitmapOnThread(image_Url,
//              Profile_image);

        AQuery aq = new AQuery(context);
        aq.id(Profile_image).image(image_Url, true, false, 0,
                R.drawable.imge);

    }

    class Uploadimage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        InputStream inputStream;
        private static final String ALLOWED_URI_CHARS = "@#&=*+-_.,:!?()/~'%";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setTitle("Updating...");
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                String Url = Uri.encode(
                        "http://api.lociiapp.com/api/registration/ProfilePictureSaved?imageFile="
                                + params[0] + "&member_id=" + member_id
                                + "&picture_path=" + member_id + ".jpg",
                        ALLOWED_URI_CHARS);

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(Url);

                httppost.setHeader(
                        "Accept",
                        "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,application/json;q=0.9,/;q=0.8");
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                System.out.println("15aug " + result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                pDialog.cancel();
                System.out.println("Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog.cancel();

        //  MtDrawableManager.getInstance().fetchBitmapOnThread(image_Url,
        //          Profile_image);
            AQuery aq = new AQuery(context);
            aq.id(Profile_image).image(image_Url, true, false, 0,
                    R.drawable.imge);

            Log.e("Image Url**************", image_Url);

        }

    }
```

this is my code fro Uploading image to server Using camera and gallery . i am able to Upload image  in both case successfully but there is Profile_image is image view where i have print that image after uploading to server i am getting image_url correctly in postexcute method but its displaying image on image view Profile_image please tell me where amd doing i am able to find issue even in on resume method i have putted same code for display image  .

Answer (score 0):

**You can try image load through image loader.
Download image loader through below link.
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/**